# IIS Express for Asp.Net Core Does Not Run in Chrome in Debug Mode

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, iis-express

I have been learning ASP.NET Core by using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. When I run a project, I generally click on the IIS Express button in the top center of the IDE. This action launches a new window in Chrome (my default browser), which up till today has worked just fine.

Today, however, it is failing to load the application. The browser says "Your application is starting..." and remains in that state. Eventually, I close the window and find that the application is still running in VS. I click the Stop Debugging button, which after a minute gives me the following message:

```
Debugging is being stopped but is not yet complete. You can force debugging to stop immediately, but any process being detached may be terminated instead. 

This window will automatically close when the debugging has completely stopped.
```

And there is a Stop Now button which I click. When I do, the output from the Diagnostics Hub is:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'StandardClientTransportConnection'.
```

I have various workarounds. I can run the project:

- Without debugging in any browser.
- With debugging in IE or Edge.
- By clicking on the project name instead of IIS Express, which I believe runs the application in regular IIS.

But I would like to understand the issue I have. I have tried the following:

- Deleting the .nuget folder under my profile.
- Deleting the IIS Express folder in my Documents folder.
- Clearing the browser data from Chrome.

All to no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017, cannot debug or run the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690548/visual-studio-2017-cannot-debug-or-run-the-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a Chrome update broke debugging from Visual Studio. This answer appears to work:

[Visual Studio 2017, cannot debug or run the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690548/visual-studio-2017-cannot-debug-or-run-the-application)

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem after a Chrome update yesterday. or if you clean all the folders and chrome this problem might occur If you switch On the Javascript debugging in options:

Tools--> Options -> Debugging -> Enable Javascript Debugging in Asp.NET

Then it runs fine.

Comment: worked in VS2022