# Visual Studio 2017, cannot debug or run the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

After I turned on my computer today, I haven't been able to debug or run the application at all. If I publish the project, it works fine. But if I run it from Visual Studio, it's just stuck loading and Visual Studio stops responding.

Here are the errors I get when I force quit the application:

> Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
>   The program '[6276] chrome.exe: WebKit' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
>   The program '[8852] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Have you ever experinced anything similar? I've been trying to look up answers but haven't been able to locate any. Also I tried on a diffrent machine, and cannot debug the application there either.

Have tried updating and reinstalling all packages using Nuget.

Best Regards Solan.

Comment: Try debugging in a different browser than Chrome. I ran into a similar problem today and that appeared to be a work around to the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We had the same problem after a Chrome update yesterday. If you switch off the Javascript debugging in options:

Options -> Debugging -> Enable Javascript Debugging in Asp.NET

Then it runs fine.

Comment: You my friend, is the proof that not all heroes wear a cape! Thanks so much been trying to solve this for 6-7 hours-.-

Comment: A pleasure to help. After we had the problem I joked with the team that Stack Overflow would soon be awash with this problem and that I should keep an eye out in case. Yours was the first one I saw :-) have a great day!

Comment: I found that IIS Express did not work with Chrome, which allowed me to narrow down to this post on SO however, I am surprised that this is documented as a known issue.  Very odd.

Comment: OMG OMG OMG you are my hero!  Even in 2023 this bug is happening using VS 2022